# Laminate flooring repair

Tags: flooring, laminate

My laminate floor looks like the top layer has "bubbled" at the seam in a couple of places.Can this be repaired?

Comment: The best way IMHO is to cut a rectangle around the problematic section, remove it, and insert a new section. It sounds like that section wasn't glued all the way down or dried out too much from when it was installed the first time

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Adding a picture of the damage to your question would help us give you a good answer.

Comment: Also, "laminate floor" is about as generic a term as there is. What flooring is it, actually?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the fake wood, floating type of laminate flooring that clicks together, you can't really repair it. This type of flooring does not handle moisture well and will bubble after being exposed to too much moisture.

Depending on where the problem plank is, if you have any extra pieces from when the floor was installed, you may be able to take apart some of the planks to get to the bubbled one, replace the bubbled one with a new one and reinstall the removed pieces.